# Whats wrong with Neo4j 2.0 Query?

Tags: cypher, neo4j

I am trying to understand why the data is not showing up in my query. I was wondering if there is any way to troubleshoot whats going on.

Here is the current issue:

I have populated some data from existing test database to check the performance with  a relation like this : `(e:Event)-[:FOR_USER]->(u:User)` when I get all  the users and look at the property, I can see the data, but when I query the users using same data it says 0 records found.

Below image shows the 2 query:
[image]

Can some one please help me understand how to debug such issue in neo4j

**EDIT**

Issue is that the Browser is somehow truncating the multiple spaces in the result. Like in this case "`User-May<space>1 2013 1:18AM`" was displayed on both webadmin and new browser, but in reality it should have been "`User-May<space><space>1 2013<space><space>1:18AM`"

So no matter what I do I can't query the value as  looks like duplicate space is truncated somewhere.

Tabular data as Micheal suggested is as below

```
{"id":"75307","labels":["User"],"properties":{"Name":"User-May  1 2013  1:18AM"}}
```

and what we are seeing is `User-May 1 2013 1:18AM`

Regards
Kiran

Comment: Try to download the tabular results I think it is just a space that gets squashed in the HTML rendering.

Comment: Thanks, It finally was the issue, there was an extra space between in between. I was wondering if there are any option to turn on logging and analyze the query and whats going on at the back end. I also noticed that when I was pumping the data in to the neo4j using the windows dialog, the system would suddenly become slow and remain slow un till i restarted the neo4j and then get another 6 to 7 hrs of normal working. So how do we analyze whats happening. Just worried what will happen if I use it in production on windows Azure

Comment: @MichaelHunger just to clarify, the issue is not solved. My comment above may look misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following Cypher syntax in the browser:

```
MATCH (user:User { Name: "User-May  1 2013  1:18AM" })
RETURN user.Name as Name
```

As far as the rendering of multiple spaces being trimmed, that is a browser specific functionality. See screenshot below for example:

[image: Browser Text Rendering]

The text itself is preserved as it is returned from the Neo4j server. As you can see when I analyze the HTML element of the browser using Firebug, the redundant spaces are indeed there.

So again, this doesn't seem to be a bug with Neo4j, it's how the browser you are using renders the text. The browser expects redundant spaces to be encoded as `&nbsp;` like so: "Testing  testing" which is HTML encoded as `Testing&nbsp;&nbsp;testing`

Comment: Hey! thanks, you are right its not an issue with the Neo4J instead with the chrome browser I was using.